# Pandas converting data to dates when importing from Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, date

I am importing an Excel file as a pandas Data frame. The data is pretty messy and the columns are not in specified data types. I am having an issue where some data will automatically be converted to a date type when it's not a date. For example I have a data point that is "1-Jan". This is a coincidence and not a date. However if I import the excel file to a dataframe it reads as "1/1/2022 00:00:00". And when I export it back to Excel it's "1/1/2022 12:00:00 AM".
I need to import it from excel as not a date, and then export it to a new excel file as well. I can not convert the column to a specific data type though because it is mixed between strings, integers, and floats. Is there a way to fix this?

This is how I am importing the file

```py
filename='excel.xlsx'

datadf=pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)
```

The data point "1-Jan" reads as "1/1/2022 00:00:00" in the dataframe. This is not supposed to be a date it is just a bad coincidence. The entire dataframe is composed of mixed data types.q

Comment: In Excel the type is associated with a cell, not with a column. You should ensure that the type of the cell containing "1-Jan" is string. You can re-type it as `'1-Jan` because the `'` forces a string type.

Comment: Please try using: datadf = pd.read_excel(filename, dtype={'Date': str}). Let me know if that helps, So I can post the answer.

Comment: datadf = pd.read_excel(filename, dtype={'Date': str}) did not fix the problem. The data imported from excel did not change in the pandas dataframe.

Comment: I can not edit the individual cells in excel to add ' before importing. There are thousands of lines of data, and this program needs to work across multiple files of similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I just had this issue and instead of fighting with pandas, I used libreoffice to convert the entire column to text and it took care of problems with date like data.

I selected "format quoted field as text"
and then selected above the column header and selected text as column type.